# Session Data in site.master

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get a value from the user session and display it in the site.master file. How can I do this so that every view page has this value? Do I have to place ViewData["MyValue"] in every controller action? Is there a global way of doing this in one place so I don't have to have the same code in every controller action?

Comment: You talk about the session object, but mention ViewData. Why can't you call `<%= Session["MyValue"] %>` in the master page?

Comment: I think my brain checked out for a minute...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<%= Session["MyValue"] %> in the master page

Answer (score 3):

You could write an action filter attribute and decorate your controller with it:

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["MyValue"] = "some value";
    }
}
```

And then decorate the controller with this attribute:

```
[CustomFilter]
public class MyController: Controller
{
    // actions
}
```

This will ensure that `ViewData["MyValue"]` will be set on all action belonging to this controller.

Comment: do you have an example of this?

Comment: Further to this, you could have your own `BaseController` with the `CustomFilter` attribute which all your individual controllers inherit from. This will mean you only have to have it in one place.